# How does .Find.Execute method work in MS Word files?

Tags: vba, methods, ms-word, find

I know it is a very basic question, but I still can't quite understand how `.Find.Execute` method works in MS Word files.

For example, I see a lot of codes with this snippet

```
Selection.Find.Execute FindText:="some text"
     Do While Selection.Find.Found         
         Selection.Find.Execute
     Loop
```

My basic questions are:

1- Is there a difference between using `.Find.Text` and `.Find.Execute FindText`?

2- Why is the while loop `Do While Selection.Find.Found` used instead of using `If Selection.Find.Found` ? Or what does it mean?

3- What is the meaning of `Selection.Find.Execute`? And what is its role at the end of the while loop?

Comment: https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/words_fickle_vba_find_property.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already posted an answer to one of your questions showing how to use that approach. In any event, using Selection is both inefficient and liable to produce excessive screen flicker. Moreover, unless you collapse the found range, you're liable to end up with an endless loop.

The following three approaches are functionally equivalent:

```
Sub Demo1()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "<[ACEMR]{3}[1-4][1-9]{2}>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute = True
    'Do whatever with the found range
    MsgBox .Text
   .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub Demo2()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "<[ACEMR]{3}[1-4][1-9]{2}>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found = True
    'Do whatever with the found range
    MsgBox .Text
   .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
   .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub Demo3()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "<[ACEMR]{3}[1-4][1-9]{2}>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute
    Do While .Found = True
      'Do whatever with the found range
      With .Parent
        MsgBox .Text
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Find.Execute
      End With
    Loop
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```